# Bootstrap 4 smooth change width of input based on content

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 inline form and I want to dynamically **smoothly** change **auto** width of the inline form elements if it is possible.

I know how to achieve that with for example `col-md-4` to `col-md-6` with `transition: width 1s ease;` but problem is with **`col-auto`**

Do you have any suggestion ?

I have this code

```
<div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="form-group row">
          <label for="pcp" class="col-auto col-form-label" title="{{ 'PRIMARY_CARE_PHYSICIAN' | translate }}">{{ 'PRIMARY_CARE_PHYSICIAN' | translate }}:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control col" placeholder="{{ 'PCP' | translate }}" ngModel name="pcp">
        </div>
      </div>
```

and it looks like like this

[image]

**Because my application will be multilanguage, english and german, the label will be changed dynamically** and for the same input I will have german version, like this...

[image]

As you can see label for german version is longer word that english, so I would like to achieve when user changed the language by click on the english or german flag, smooth shrink of input proportional to the length of the label.

If you have some question , feel free to ask me, I will explain in more detail.

Thank you in advance

Comment: `col-auto` means: take as little space as possible. There's nothing to transition to.

Comment: Yes, I know. Do you have any suggestion how to achieve that? is it the only way to do that with for example col-md-5 or some other , to col-md-7 or some other ?